# Proper usage of Digital Signature (DSC) fields nf PDF documents

Tags: pdf, certificates, okular, signature

I'm researching and wanting to use digital signature for my future documents. My Windows installation came with Nitro PDF that I use to build a PDF form with 3 signature fields. I could also set a condition to lock all fields when the document is digitally signed with certificates.

In my mind, this is how a PDF form is supposed to work:

1. A person fill and complete the PDF form,
2. The person signs the document **by the provided signature field**

Now on Ubuntu (most of my work is done in Ubuntu), filling and signing PDF documents seems a lot more complicated. I've searched and tried some solutions and most of them are either:

- Signature as an annotation only. Signing a document doesn't actually lock a document with a certificate, it only adds the signature scribble (for lack of better word).
- Separate annotation and signing. For example, you would annotate your signature scribble in xournal++, then sign in using gpg. This kinda works but it defeats the purpose of the 3 signature fields and each of their conditions. People can add annotation wherever they want and it does not bind to a certificate.
- The closest I got is with Okular. It detects the 3 signature fields and I can choose which field I want to sign, however I can't change how the signature looks when printed. There's an option to digitally sign with scribble and certificate, but it creates a new signature field rather than filling any of the 3 signature fields.

I've also tried LibreOffice Draw, but I can't seem to add anything in it, it's unresponsive.

What is the best/proper way to do digital signature in Ubuntu?